# Using jenkins how to upload file from windows using file parameter and save it remote linux workspace location for execution

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

> I have set up Jenkins on the Linux server. In the Jenkins URL - using the freestyle project, I have used one file parameter with the name 'patch_txt_file_loc' to upload the file and saved the project. Now I need to browse and select any text file from the local windows disc and the file has to be copied to the remote Linux node. Later I need to 'cat' the file contents. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [File Parameters plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/) for this. Here is an example.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    base64File 'yamlFile'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        withFileParameter('yamlFile') {
          def configVal = readYaml file: yamlFile
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```